# Unable to access port 3306 for mySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have enabled this through windows Firewall. (I use Avast Free which doesn't have a free firewall) and I have went onto the BT router to port forward this too. Yet I still get system error 10060. I have downloaded PfPortchecker and checked port 3306 and apparently it's still not open.

I am pretty clueless on what to do here, any help is appreciated cheers.

Comment: Please clarify what your setup is here. So far it sounds like you are running a mysql server at home and attempting to access it from elsewhere, correct?

Comment: Hello, I have installed MySQLworkbench and I'm trying to connect to localhost. 127.0.0.1, port:3306, username: root. But I keep getting the error above and for some reason it seems I am completely unable to open port 3306.

Comment: Are you sure the server's connection setup in `my.cnf` is correct? Things like its port option, bind-address, whether you've got skip-networking?

Comment: Also, bear in mind that `-h localhost` at the MySQL command line is not the same as `-h 127.0.0.1`, although I'm not sure that's relevant here!

Comment: If you're doing this locally, you should not be punching holes in your router firewall.  Verify that mysqld is actually running and on port 3306 first.

Comment: I did try using localhost too and still got the same error. I had the same problem with ASP connecting remotely last night too. It seems that I cannot do anything because port 3306 is not opened. But I have port forwarded it on both my modem and windows firewall.

Comment: It fails on the "Test connection" part giving the error: failed to connect to MySQL at 127.0.0.1:3306 with user root and error 10060

Comment: I tried doing telnet localhost 3306 on CMD< this also fails saying could not open connection to host.

Answer (score 0):

If both MySQL Workbench and your MySQL server run on the same machine then you don't need to open any port on the modem or in the firewall. Focus on problems on your local machine.

First thing to check is: is your server actually running? Is there a service that starts the MySQL server? What setup is that? Did you install the server via the MySQL Windows Installer? If the server is running check the config file if TCP/IP networking is disabled for some weird reason (it should not, but who knows). If that is disabled you can only connect via a named pipe to your server.

Next step is to check is that the user you use to connect is actually allowed to connect from the local machine. Jeremy is right here, it matters if you use localhost or 127.0.0.1, especially if IPv6 is enabled on the box (where localhost resolves to ::1, instead of 127.0.0.1).